# Determine logger based on Akka Actor's path *NOT* the Actor's class (Logback, Akka 2.1.4)

Tags: playframework, akka, logback

I'm using Play 2.1.1 with Akka 2.1.4 and Logback baked in. event-handler is set to SLF4jLoggerEventHandler.  I'd like my application-logger.xml to look like this:

`<logger name="actors.user.someActorParent" .. />`

Where that would be a definition for someActorParent and all it's descendent actors.

**However, no matter what I do the logger seems to be determined by the class of the Actor, not the actor path.**

Following http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.4/scala/logging.html  I implemented LogSource in such a way that, given an Actor object, it would return the path as "grandparent.parent.me" instead of "akka://blah/blah."  All this really seems to effect is the akkaSource MDC variable.  The logger is still determined by the package of the Actor's class.

This is consistent with what I see in akka.event.Logging.scala and Slf4jEventHandler.scala.

**How do I configure logback with Akka 2.1.4 so that I can define loggers based on Actor path, no the package the Actor's class belongs to?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logger will be chosen based on the logSource string only if the `LogSource.getClazz` method returns the class `akka.event.DummyClassForStringSources`. Since you have written your `LogSource` already, just override as show [here](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.1.4/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/event/Logging.scala#L266).

The code which decides it can be found [here](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.1.4/akka-slf4j/src/main/scala/akka/event/slf4j/Slf4jEventHandler.scala#L36).

Comment: Perfect... I don't know how I missed this. The answer was staring me in the face the whole time.  Re-implemented LogSource::getClazz and everything is working swimmingly.